# Openshift App not redirecting from openshift app url to my custon domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, openshift

I'm hosting wordpress site on free Openshift from redhat. The default openshift app url for my app is: namanboard-namanwp.rhcloud.com . I set up its alias with my custom domain `www.namanboard.com` . I also added the CNAME to my domain provider i.e. `bigrock.in` and my custom domain is properly working and getting data from my app.

But when I visit the url of my opensource app, it does not redirect to my custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpenShift is supposed to automatically configure such a redirect. You would need to modify your `.htaccess` file in the WordPress app with appropriate rewrite rules. [Here](http://www.theirishpenguin.com/2012/09/11/search-engine-friendly-redirects-for-custom-domains-on-openshift-using-a-htaccess-file.html) you can find some guidance.

Comment: I tried but when I visit my openshift url it shows can't redirect properly plus some of the content on my wordpress site don't appear correctly.

Comment: I think you should post more details to improve your chances others will address the question. I would start with what is your `.htaccess` content now, exact errors in the logs, what has been tried, what content does not appear correctly and what you have changed in your WordPress admin config (if anything).

Comment: leave it I started a new application on openshift and restored my backup on that. Now please tell me how to make the openshift app url disable for google indexing.

Comment: To have your `robots.txt` accessible on your domain, place it in `<yourApp>/php/robots.txt` and git push to deploy it.